# Screeps autospawner not 'totally' working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, screeps

So I tried to update my screeps script and well.. uhm.. something went wrong, because my autospawner code is stuck in a loop. I'm still fairly new to JavaScript so it's probably some stupid mistake I made. What I have tried to do is to get a Reference error for what is wrong by adding a console.log to the if statement... got nothing except for a 'harvester spawned' message that gets spammed into my console. I'm really struggling. Pls help me!

*If you need any extra info pls say so, i'm happy to provide anything that you need!*

```
const roleHarvester = require('role.harvester');
const roleUpgrader = require('role.upgrader');
const roleBuilder = require('role.builder');

module.exports.loop = function () {

for(let name in Memory.creeps) {
    if(!Game.creeps[name]) {
        delete Memory.creeps[name];
    }
}

//change to object
let minimum = {
    NumberOfHarvesters: 3,
    NumberOfUpgraders: 3,
    NumberOfBuilders: 3
}
let numberOf = {
    Harvesters: _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => c.memory.role == 'harvester'),
    Upgraders: _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => c.memory.role == 'upgraders'),
    Builders: _.sum(Game.creeps, (c) => c.memory.role == 'builders')
}

if (numberOf.Harvesters < 3) {
    Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE], {role: 'harvester'})
    console.log('harvester spawned');
} 
else if (numberOf.Upgraders < 3) {
    Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE], {role: 'upgrader'})
    console.log('upgrader spawned');
} 
else if (numberOf.Builders < 3) {
    Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, MOVE], {role: 'builder'})
    console.log('builder spawned');
}
else {
    Game.spawns.Spawn1.createCreep([WORK, CARRY, MOVE], {role: 'upgrader'})
}   

for(let name in Game.creeps) {
    let creep = Game.creeps[name];
    if(creep.memory.role == 'harvester') {
        roleHarvester.run(creep);
    }
    if(creep.memory.role == 'upgrader') {
        roleUpgrader.run(creep);
    }
    if(creep.memory.role == 'builder') {
        roleBuilder.run(creep);
    } 
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Completely unrelated to yohr question but you are iterating Game.creeps 3 times to count. If you have a lot of Creeps this will be highly inefficient. You might want to change the sum to a `_.groupBy(Game.creeps, c => c.memory.role);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the timestamps from the console, your code is not "stuck in a loop" so much as it is in the main loop. Every tick where `numberOf.Harvesters < 3` evaluates to `true`, the code in the `if` block will be executed. Assuming the creep counting part is working, this means it will keep executing until you have at least 3 harvesters.

Perhaps you should add some code to check if the spawn is already spawning another creep and if there is enough available energy before calling `Spawn1.createCreep()`. This will greatly reduce the chatter in your console.

If there are already 3 harvesters, try adding something like `console.log('harvester count: ' + numberOf.Harvesters);` right before the if statement.